# How to post on my friend's Facebook Wall using koala gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-wall

I am trying to post a message on my friend's Facebook wall using Koala Gem in my Web Application.

I am trying using the following code

```
@user.put_wall_post("Hey, Welcome to the Web Application!!!!",{:name => "Friend's Name"} )
```

I have also tried replacing the name of my friend with his Facebook Id, but it is of no help...

```
@user.put_wall_post("Hey, Welcome to the Web Application!!!!",{:name => "10001010101010"} )
```

But, both the above methods post the message on my wall. What am I wrong with??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name symbol doesn't represent the name of the user on Facebook but the title of the message! Try this instead:

```
@user.put_wall_post("Hey, Welcome to the Web Application!!!!", {:name => "..."}, "id_of_your_friend")
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: I have found that when I write the unique username of my friend in the last(i.e. name_of_friend) then the post gets successfully posted, but not when I simply use the name of my friend....

Comment: Finally got the solution to my problem, you have to simply put the facebook id of the person instead of name_of_friend in the last...